# Best practice regarding controllers for a resource that can have different parent classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently trying to refactor some controller code and I came accross some code that I'm not sure how to implement in a correct way.

My application has users and companies, and both can have projects.
The current situation is that we have 2 urls:

- example.com/projects/*action (for user projects)
- example.com/company/:company_id/projects/*action (for company projects)

Those will route to the same controller which will handle the request differently based on if a company_id exists or not. This is not very clean in my opinion so I have been thinking about a better way to do this.

So far, I think the best way is to split them up in seperate controllers, like:

- Users::ProjectsController
- Companies::ProjectsControler

But since the only difference between a user project and a company project is pretty much that one has a 'user_id' and the other has a 'company_id', it feels like that will not be very DRY as I'll be writing a lot of duplicate code.

The current solution probably isn't as much of a problem, but I want to do this the correct way, so was hoping that someone over here would have a suggestion on how to handle this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is how my ProjectsController#create currently looks

```
  def create
    if params[:company_id]
      company = current_user.get_companies.find(params[:company_id])
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.company_id = company.id
    else
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.user_id = current_user.id
    end
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Project '#{@project.name}' created."
      if @project.company
        redirect_to company_project_path(@project.company, @project)
      else
        redirect_to project_path(@project)
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = @project.errors.full_messages
      if params[:company_id]
        redirect_to new_company_project_path(params[:company_id], @project)
      else
        redirect_to new_project_path(@project)
      end
    end
  end
```

It's mainly the if/else logic I'd like to get rid off
So i should probably just add company_id and user_id to the permitted_params and let use a function to put either one of them in the params...

Comment: Can you please show us some code? It's very hard to make any suggestion for improvements without knowing what it looks like currently.

Comment: I **suspect** (!!) that despite you saying *"this is not very clean in my opinion"*, there is a simple way to handle this `user_id` vs `company_id` in one place in the controller, which is relatively clean.

Comment: You're probably right, I guess you're thinking about just letting a before_action handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you said the only difference is associating `company_id` vs `user_id`, as @TomLord said, you might find something like below work for you:

Assuming that you are using [shallow nested routes](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting):

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  COLLECTION_ACTIONS = [:index, :new, :create].freeze
  MEMBER_ACTIONS = [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy].freeze

  before_action :set_associated_record, only: COLLECTION_ACTIONS
  before_action :set_project, only: MEMBER_ACTIONS

  def index
    @projects = @associated_record.projects
    # ...
  end

  def new
    @project = @associated_record.projects.new
    # ...
  end

  def create
    @project = @associated_record.projects.new(project_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_company
    if params[:company_id].present?
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end
  end

  # you might want to remove this set_user method, because perhaps you are already setting @user from sesssion
  def set_user
    if params[:user_id].present?
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def set_associated_record
    set_company
    set_user
    @associated_record = @company || @user
  end
end
```

Comment: A looks similar to what I ended up with, thanks!
Any reason for the set_associated_record to set an instance variable instead of just returning the associated record like I did in my owner method?

Comment: No prob! :) Not needed until the point in time in the future where you would want to use them in the views. i.e. maybe you'd want to show `@company.name` in `#index` or some action Also, I guess it helps programmers / me to have a peace of mind: i.e. anywhere in the code, I can just call `@company` or `@user` to check if they exist or call a method upon them. The downside though is they take up a very very small footprint in memory as they are stored as instance variable. But, still you could choose not to use instance variable as you wish :)

Comment: oh also, by the way setting as instance variable means that the value is already cached, unlike if you are gonna be calling `owner` multiple times (just in case if ever you call them multiple times), which then calls the `owner` method multiple times as well, and therefore better to just call them once-off, and is why I set them immediately already as instance variable in the before_action sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I managed to handle it in a way that I'm happy with.
ProjectsController#create now looks like this:

```
  def create
    @project = owner.projects.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Project '#{@project.name}' created."
      redirect_to action: :show, id: @project.id
    else
      flash[:error] = @project.errors.full_messages
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def owner
    if params[:company_id]
      return policy_scope(Company).find(params[:company_id])
    else
      return current_user
    end
  end
```

I added the owner class to return the entity that the project belongs to.
Any suggestions for improvements are still welcome though!